# JS querySelectorAll for

Tags: javascript, html, queryselectorall

Cкрипт по идее должен искать у span класс active и потом выполнять действие.

Использую для этого querySelectorAll, но нужно зациклить, чтобы работало через for, я так понимаю, но не получается.

```js
let div = document.querySelectorAll('#naviwka span');

if (div.classList.contains('active')) {
  div.scrollIntoView({
    inline: "center"
  });

} else {
  alert('Class does not exist');
}
```

```html
<header class="example-one-header scroll">
  <nav class="vertical-align-middle" id="naviwka">
    <span class="nav-item">HOME</span>
    <span class="nav-item">ABOUT US</span>
    <span class="nav-item">POSSIBILITIES</span>
    <span class="nav-item">IMMERSE</span>
    <span class="nav-item">WHY OCTAGON?</span>
    <span class="nav-item active" id="nav_it">BUILD YOUR FUTURE</span>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Если вы хотите получить ровно один элемент, то зачем здесь цикл вообще? `document.querySelector('#naviwka .nav-item.active').scrollIntoView({inline: "center"})`

Comment: Уже решил) хотел удалять вопрос. Ваш метод как говорится всё гениальное просто, работает))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) [возращает](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#return_value) [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#return_value), у котрого есть метод [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). Применить его можно так:

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('#naviwka span');

spans.forEach((span) => {
  if (span.classList.contains('active')) span.classList.add('sure');
  else console.log('Class does not exis');
});
```

```css
.nav-item.active.sure {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<header class="example-one-header scroll">
  <nav class="vertical-align-middle" id="naviwka">
    <span class="nav-item">HOME</span>
    <span class="nav-item">ABOUT US</span>
    <span class="nav-item">POSSIBILITIES</span>
    <span class="nav-item">IMMERSE</span>
    <span class="nav-item">WHY OCTAGON?</span>
    <span class="nav-item active" id="nav_it">BUILD YOUR FUTURE</span>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Но, если вам просто нужно найти элемент, у которого есть класс `active`, то можно обойтись и без цикла и воспользоваться методом [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
const span = document.querySelector('#naviwka span.active');

span.classList.add('sure');
```

```css
.nav-item.active.sure {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<header class="example-one-header scroll">
  <nav class="vertical-align-middle" id="naviwka">
    <span class="nav-item">HOME</span>
    <span class="nav-item">ABOUT US</span>
    <span class="nav-item">POSSIBILITIES</span>
    <span class="nav-item">IMMERSE</span>
    <span class="nav-item">WHY OCTAGON?</span>
    <span class="nav-item active" id="nav_it">BUILD YOUR FUTURE</span>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Да, это оно, спасибо. Но уже сам разобрался)
Отмечу как ответ.